# Windows 10 client can't ping/reach/lookup specific hosts in a network

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, windows-10-v1511, windows-10-v1607

I have a strange problem with a Windows 10 client in a customer network. It's a Lenovo ThinkPad Carbon X1. The client was first upgraded from Windows 8.1 to 10. Everything related to networking worked perfectly. All hosts were reachable. Internet access worked.

Then there were some upgrade related problems with Windows Updates and so we decided to reinstall the machine. I've reinstalled the machine with Windows 10 Pro Build 1511 image and also did a BIOS update. After that installed all drivers from the Lenovo page and installed Windows Updates. Internet worked. But some hosts in the network were not reachable. Every host in the IP range `192.168.0.1-9` were not reachable. No ping, no dns lookup. Wifi or ethernet doesn't matter. DHCP or static IP changed nothing. All other hosts can be accessed perfectly. And all connections from another host to the these hosts work.

In the meanwhile we've reinstalled the machine 2 times. Upgraded to the new Windows 10 Build 1607. But that also doesn't help.
Today I've installed a Windows 10 VM on a ESXi host in this network from the exact same install image I've used for the installation of this client. And surprise: Everything works...

Is there anything we oversee?

I'd be very thankful for every little hint.

Comment: Any chance there's some automatically installed/preinstalled Lenovo stuff on there adding that IP range to the Windows firewall or anything similar?

Comment: No I've installed from a original Microsoft Windows 10 ISO not from Lenovo recovery. And I've also tried connecting after I've turned off the Windows Firewall completely.

Comment: It may happen even with official sources. Some of their computers have that crapware bundled in their UEFI firmware. Have you tried a trace route rather than pings only?

Comment: Yea i've tried traceroute. It hops to the router and then stops. But there are no Firewall rules or MAC filters configured in the router. Other clients can traceroute to all hosts.

Comment: Any chance this is the only WiFi client? Some routers don't allow WiFi to WiFi connections by default.

Comment: There is no difference. It doesn't work when I connect it via ethernet or WiFi... And all the other hosts are connected via ethernet.
And the router allows WiFi to WiFi connections. I've checked it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43517/discussion-between-toxel-and-mario).